# the managed metadata service or connection is currently not available"

Tags: sharepoint-2013

For Sharepoint 2013 central admin, after creating managed metadata service it shows an error:

```
the managed metadata service or connection is currently not available
```

Comment: Can anyone help me with this , I am facing this issue after creation of managed metadata service , I want to know whether its a permission issue or its something else

Answer (score 0):

I got similar case some days ago, even the service had started.

[image]

After I did iisrest, everything works fine.

[image]